# Null checking of any property in a long nested call

Tags: c#, func

Difficult to explain in words, so I'll provide an example.

I want to output this in Razor (but it doesn't matter that it's razor, my question is about c#):

```
@SomeClass.SomeClass.SomeClass.ID.ToString()
```

Any of the SomeClass can be null (it's an external api which I don't really have influence on)

So I tried this:

```
@functions{
    private string Safe(Func<string> val, string defaultValue)
    {        
        try 
        {
            return val.Invoke();
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And then this:

```
@Safe(SomeClass.SomeClass.SomeClass.ID.ToString, "value not found")
```

But no cigar ... 
Is there any way to achieve this? Thx.

UPDATE1:
Using a NullReferenceException is obviously much beter.

Comment: In any case, don't use exception handling for control flow. You are swallowing *all* exceptions here. You'll never discover crashes, but your users will.

Comment: better catch specific Exceptions. you can always catch NullPointerException and let the rest fall through.

Comment: You are both absolutely correct. I'll alter the example.

Comment: Do not even catch NullRefException! Those should be reserved for bugs, because in >>90% of the cases they are. Just never cause a NullRefEx by convention.; This code is such a horrible idea to me.

Comment: I understand an appreciate your input, usr. But that doesn't exactly solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the whole call:

```
@Safe(() => SomeClass.SomeClass.SomeClass.ID.ToString(), "value not found")
```

The reason you have to do it this way, is because now the exception will occur inside your method. Otherwise it will already throw a NullReferenceException before it can get to the ToString-method.

Comment: The heavens open and a bright light shines on Kenneth, in the distance a choir can be heard singing in one voice '_hallelujah_'. In other words: this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're pretty close. The problem here is that passing the ToString function requires that you be able to resolve ToString, which requires all of the objects in the chain to be non-null. Try passing a lambda in instead of the ToString function, which will defer that lookup until you try to evaluate it (inside the lambda):

```
@Safe(() => SomeClass.SomeClass.SomeClass.ID.ToString(), "value not found")
```

Comment: Thx, but since Kenneth was a tad earlier, all I have is an upvote for you.